Rust program crashes in release build
I have a program which loads a C++ library to query its version number via its exported function. The foreign function returns C++ std::string that I use with the cxx crate in Rust. The code produces significantly different behaviour when it is built with debug mode and release mode.
unsafe {
    let lib = Library::new("liblogic.so").unwrap();
    let logic_getVersion: Symbol<unsafe extern "C" fn() -> *const CxxString> = lib.get(b"getVersion").unwrap();
    println!("logic.getVersion={:?}", logic_getVersion);
    let ptr_version = std::hint::black_box(logic_getVersion());
    println!("ptr_version={:?}", ptr_version);
    let cxx_version = std::hint::black_box(ptr_version.as_ref().unwrap());
    println!("cxx_version={:p}", &cxx_version);
    assert_eq!(ptr_version, &*cxx_version);
    let ptr_version_cstr = std::hint::black_box(cxx_version.as_ptr());          // <= Release build gets invalid pointer here!!!
    println!("ptr_version_cstr={:?}", ptr_version_cstr);
    let mut strbuffer = [0_u8; 16];
    println!("strbuffer.as_mut_ptr()={:?}", strbuffer.as_mut_ptr());
    println!("strbuffer.len()={}", strbuffer.len());
    std::ptr::copy(ptr_version_cstr, strbuffer.as_mut_ptr(), strbuffer.len());
    println!("Logic version: {:?}", strbuffer);
    let str_version = std::str::from_utf8(&strbuffer).unwrap();
    println!("{str_version}");
}

Output of the debug build:
logic.getVersion=Symbol "getVersion"@0x76b6dac04c15 from "/opt/local/lib/liblogic.so"
ptr_version=0x7ffefd18bc70
cxx_version=0x7ffefd18bd20
ptr_version_cstr=0x55ad67ac3528
strbuffer.as_mut_ptr()=0x7ffefd18be10
strbuffer.len()=16
Logic version: [49, 46, 48, 46, 50, 55, 45, 83, 78, 65, 80, 83, 72, 79, 84, 0]
1.0.27-SNAPSHOT

Output of the release build:
logic.getVersion=Symbol "getVersion"@0x749eee404c15 from "/opt/local/lib/liblogic.so"
ptr_version=0x568a0b899510
cxx_version=0x7fff67901ec8
ptr_version_cstr=0x737265765f787863
strbuffer.as_mut_ptr()=0x7fff67901ef0
strbuffer.len()=16
Segmentation fault

What is apparent is that I get significantly different pointers each time. I'd expect ptr_version, cxx_version and ptr_version_cstr to be somewhat close to each other which is true with the debug build. But the release build gives me a pointer that is visibly off:
ptr_version_cstr=0x737265765f787863

This is the result of a CxxString.as_ptr() call in order to get the C *char to finally access the characters of the version string.
Obviously, the crash happens with the std::ptr::copy call which I added to try to copy the C string to a safe buffer before constructing a Rust str from it. Originally I constructed the str right from the buffer returned by the library, which also worked in debug and crashed the release.
I suspect Rust optimizes something away in release mode which would be essential for the program to not crash, so I added the std::hint::black_box calls, but it didn't help anything. I also suspect Rust moves the values because it doesn't know that it shouldn't touch memory managed by the guest library, so I tried to Pin the values but it didn't help either.
Note that I have very aggressive optimization settings because I want to produce as small binary as possible.
[profile.release]
lto = true
opt-level = "z"
strip = true

But turning them off doesn't help. I have no idea what's going on. Even if the library does something nasty, I couldn't explain why it works with the debug build.

UPDATE: I simplified the source to this (turned out the previous one moved the CxxString which should never happen), but it didn't help. It still looks better because I can get rid of raw pointer dereferences and use &CxxString which is treated as a native Rust borrow.
let lib = unsafe { Library::new("liblogic.so").unwrap() };
let logic_getVersion: Symbol<unsafe extern "C" fn() -> &'a CxxString> = unsafe { lib.get(b"getVersion").unwrap() };
println!("logic.getVersion={:?}", logic_getVersion);
let cxx_version = pin!(std::hint::black_box(unsafe { logic_getVersion() }));
println!("&cxx_version={:p}", cxx_version);
let ptr_version_cstr = std::hint::black_box(cxx_version.as_ptr());          // <= Release build gets invalid pointer here!!!
println!("cxx_version.len()={}; ptr_version_cstr={:?}", cxx_version.len(), ptr_version_cstr);
println!("cxx_version.as_bytes().len()={}", cxx_version.as_bytes().len());
let end_index = cxx_version.as_bytes().iter().position(|&c| c == 0).unwrap();
println!("end_index={end_index}");
let buf_version = &cxx_version.as_bytes()[..end_index];
println!("buf_version={:?}", buf_version);
let str_version = std::str::from_utf8(buf_version).unwrap();
println!("{str_version}");

The current output:
logic.getVersion=Symbol "getVersion"@0x75becd804c15 from "/opt/local/lib/liblogic.so"
&cxx_version=0x7ffc12baf340
cxx_version.len()=3996997709695248755; ptr_version_cstr=0x7265765f78786326
cxx_version.as_bytes().len()=2913377524265152361
Segmentation fault

It's strange how .len() reports a surreal length for the string, but the debug build does the same and works:
logic.getVersion=Symbol "getVersion"@0x7c17a5204c15 from "/opt/local/lib/liblogic.so"
&cxx_version=0x7ffea69ea380
cxx_version.len()=9223372036854775825; ptr_version_cstr=0x5f0608e47938
cxx_version.as_bytes().len()=9223372036854775825
end_index=15
buf_version=[49, 46, 48, 46, 50, 55, 45, 83, 78, 65, 80, 83, 72, 79, 84]
1.0.27-SNAPSHOT

The cxx crate's documentation mentions to declare a bridge with [#cxx::bridge], but it wants to link the declared function at compile time, while the library is supposed to be loaded at runtime. I'm not sure if I must declare a bridge for the crate to work, because it seems to bridge std::string anyway.

ANOTHER UPDATE: With GDB, I found that the bridge to the libstdc++ library's std::string functions (e.g. cxxbridge1$cxx_string$data) are completely optimized out. They are literally just 2 instructions immediately returning. In the debug build they are implemented properly, eventually calling C++ basic_string functions. Now the question is why Rust is optimizing out function calls those are indeed getting used and how to prevent this behaviour.

If your C++ function returns std::string then extern "C" fn() -> *const CxxString is wrong.

In addition to what @kmdreko said, note the ABI of C++ types such as std::string is not the C ABI, so extern "C" is wrong.

@kmdreko I checked the function signature and I was wrong: the library returns a pointer to std::string, thus expecting a pointer is correct (typedef std::string (*getVersion_t)();).
@ChayimFriedman I see, but it doesn't accept extern "C++" (Invalid ABI), and if I declare it in [cxx::bridge], it wants to link the library at compile time that I don't want.

@MegaBrutal You are mistaken, std::string (*getVersion_t)() defines getVersion_t as a function pointer that takes no parameters and returns a std::string. So your Rust type for the function signature is still wrong.

@kmdreko OK, I tried changing the Rust signature to unsafe extern "C" fn() -> CxxString, but now even the debug build crashes. The debug build works when the signature is unsafe extern "C" fn() -> &'a CxxString, so it must return a pointer.

The debug build working doesn't mean its right. And -> CxxString doesn't work for a different reason, sure it matches now but std::string can't exist as a stack-value in Rust. There is documentation on CxxString that describes why. You need your C++ side to return unique_ptr<std::string> or similar. I suspect that debug works because you're still hitting an ABI issue as mentioned by Chayim such that returning a pointer appears to work. I'm not familiar enough with C++'s non-ABI to know if that is plausible or not. (no comment on your latest "optimized out" update)

We cannot answer this question without details about how the function is declared in C++. Please include it. Also add platform details, i.e. the compiler that was used to compile the C++ library.

In particular, as I said, the ABI of C++ is not defined and is compiler-dependent. Assuming the library function is declared as returning std::string*, the C++ standard imposes no constraints on its ABI even if it is declared with extern "C". Consequently, you cannot handle this in a cross-platform way. The Itanium ABI (clang and gcc) define this to be the same as extern "C" function returning a pointer, so if you are compiling for it, this is not the issue...

...MSVC does not define its ABI, so I don't know how it returns this value, which means that if you're compiling for it, this might be your problem, but that also means you basically cannot use this function from Rust with MSVC.

Another note, CXX is intended to be usage with static linking. You are using it with dynamic linking, which means your usage is not supported. It may work or may not, but you cannot complain if it does not.

@ChayimFriedman Unfortunately, I have no access to the library's source code, so I could only ask the author. It is compiled with GCC (GNU C++). It also links to Qt4 and uses QStrings internally, but it shouldn't be relevant here as it exports std::string. I also suspect cxx is not suitable to my current use case, but I don't know what could be the alternative. I'm still thinking that Rust is optimizing out the bridge in release mode (while in debug it does not), however I don't know how to prevent that.

So you are trying to guess the signature? This won't end good. Ask them indeed. And if you can write your own C++ example that demonstrates the behavior (based on the signature), way better.
